# Aurelia setRoot with browser Back button?

Tags: aurelia

On the web app we are working with we have three roots.

1. Auth root

   - this handles the front end of the app and the login process
2. Fetch root

   - this is used to query the database and fetch initial information on the user
   - there are four types of users which require slightly different data
3. Admin root

   - this is the root of the admin areas, after auth and fetch have processed.

How it works after login is the app will go to fetch to 'fetch' the bootstrap code that is then used within all Admin routes.

There is a hierarchy of user levels;
- Super admin sees all admins
- Admin sees all agents
- Agents see all users
- User only sees their account.

If logging in as a `super admin`, `admin` or `agent` you need to navigate down to the user level.
This is done by selecting an account, this will then re-run fetch and grab the next level of accounts on that given user level.

At the moment I have it switching routes and updating the url no problems thanks to Dwayne here https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/07/aurelia-routing-switching-root-using-setroot/.

The problem is that I need to keep the browser history, so when the back button is clicked, it needs to 're-run' that page so to speak.

I have this following code

```
this.router.navigate(url, { replace: false, trigger: false });
this.aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('views/masters/fetch'));
```

This works great, it swaps out the root, re-runs the code and updates the address bar correctly, however, when i click the back button all that happens is the URL updates, but the page does not 're-run'.

I have tried to pop this in but doesn't seem to do anything

```
  determineActivationStrategy() {
    return activationStrategy.replace;
  }
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue, or maybe offer a slightly different solution that will work with this?

Comment: To me, you are using wrong aurelia feature to implement your logic. Yes the setRoot  can dynamically load different root on app start, but that is before/above aurelia-router maintained history. Why not fix setRoot to one static component, then use a top level router to dynamically load 3 different areas of your app?

Comment: @huocp I didn't see this message come in, unfortunately, we are unable to update the way this is working.  I have a workaround at the moment that seems to have fixed the issue for the time being by adding a pre-auth route and checking the url paremeters